Extracting & summing data from a single cell in excel
I am trying to isolate some data contained within a cell in excel:

The idea is to add up all numbers before the "-" in the notes column. The data must all be contained within the same cell, as there are hundreds of lines on the full spreadsheet.
I.e. 4.3+0.8+4...
The amount of lines in the "Notes" cells will vary.
I tried using =TEXTBEFORE as below:
=TEXTBEFORE((NOTES CELL),"-",1)

and summing multiple TEXTBEFORE functions, but it becomes very messy with multiple lines inside the cell & needs to be adjusted based on how many lines are inside the cell.
I think I'm having an issue with the fact there is data inside the cell that I need to ignore (the 295### number).
Is this achievable?

=SUM(--REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".+(?=-)",1))

Try using the following formula:


=SUM(--TEXTBEFORE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,CHAR(10)),"-"))


Or,
=SUM(--TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-",CHAR(10)),,1))


Or as suggested by P.b Sir.
=SUM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-",CHAR(10))*{1,0})



Or the same but different: =SUM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-",CHAR(10))*{1,0})

@P.b Sir, nice!!
